# Backbone.Model `defaults` interfering with `set`?

Tags: backbone.js

I notice when I have code like: **http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/1/**

```
window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "title": ""  
    },
    validate: function() {
        if (this.get("title") === "")
            return "Title is missing!"            
    }
});

var todo = new Todo();
console.log("Expects blank: ", todo.get("title"));

todo.set({ title: "A valid title" });
console.log("Expects 'A valid title': ", todo.get("title"));

todo.set("title", "");
console.log("Expects blank: ", todo.get("title"));
```

All `set(...)` seems to fail: `todo.get("title")` always returns empty string

However, if I remove the `defaults`, I get expected output: **http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/2/**

```
window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function() {
        if (this.get("title") === "")
            return "Title is missing!"            
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is the problem. Once the model is created with a validate function. Every set is validated using that function. **If you do not specify attributes during construction** the defaults are applied for you automatically. Hence `var todo = new Todo();` will make `title=""` and `todo.set({title:"Valid title"});` will fail because your validate function returns a error. All you need to do is `var todo = new Todo({title:"A New Title"});`

Comment: I think I lost you at "*and `todo.set({title:"Valid title"})` will fail because your validate function returns a error*". Why will set `title = "Valid title"` fail? U mean the constructor will fail or something?

Comment: you might take a look at this fiddle i made for you http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

validate isn't getting the model as it's context so you need to work with the function attributes, then it works as intended (except validate prevents the title being set to blank)

http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/3/

no, that's not true, is it.. validate does get the model as it's context, but validate runs before the values are set in the model so it always fails when the default is set to "" but succeeds without default because undefined ! === "".

ok, I think I got it that time..

Comment: ["**validate** is called before `set` and `save`, and is passed the model attributes updated with the values from `set` or `save`."](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate), so yeah, you got it that time, +1.

Comment: Oh, so I think your version makes sense, validate will prevent the model from ever going into an invalid state. However, how do you explain why in **[version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/2/)**, without the `defaults`, `set("title", "")` will succeed?

Comment: that's because, without the defaults, validation passes because undefined is not an empty string (which is what your validator is checking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/MtULf/4/

Comment: ie. without the defaults this.get("title") returns undefined.

Comment: I think this also brings me to my next problem. If I need to know if the previous `set()` was valid, how can I do that? Since Backbone validation is preventing the model from ever going into an invalid state. I know theres an `error` event, what if I need to know the validity at that point (not using a callback)?

Comment: do you mean to test if set succeeded? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set

Comment: "If the model has a validate method, it will be validated before the attributes are set, no changes will occur if the validation fails, and set will return false. Otherwise, set returns a reference to the model. "

Comment: I figured I could use [http://pastebin.com/Uq0Bhdxd](http://pastebin.com/Uq0Bhdxd)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12190/discussion-between-lecstor-and-jm2)